Deriving 2D DFT from 1D DFT in matrix form
The one dimensional DFT of a function of one variable $f(n)$ can be stated in matrix form $$F=W^Tf$$
where $W$ is the matrix of the usual "Fourier basis" vectors. If $f$ is now a function of two variables; a matrix, then according to my lecture notes the equation can now be stated as $$[F_1\space F_2 \space ...\space F_M] =W^T[f_1\space f_2 \space ...\space f_M]$$
Quote the notes: "the columns of $F$ are now DFT's of the columns of $f$". I think this means that the 2D DFT can be written using 1D DFT's in some sense. How can this statement be justified and does this statement explain the conclusion, which reads $$F_2 = W^TF^T$$
From the last equation it is easy to show that the 2D DFT, $F_2$, is $$F_2 = W^Tf^TW$$

This may not be what you were looking for, but you can generate a $\sf 2D$ (or $\sf 3D$) transform from a $\sf 1D$ transform via a helix transform.
